# How to resize h264 video with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a raw .h264 video with resolution 1920x1080 and I want to resize to 1280x720 in the same format (h264) using ffmpeg. I found examples on doing that but to mp4 (https://askubuntu.com/questions/690015/how-can-i-convert-264-file-to-mp4) but I actually want to resize to .h264 format (no container)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [scale filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale):

```
ffmpeg -i input.h264 -vf scale=1280:720 output.h264
```

If `ffmpeg` assumes an incorrect frame rate (refer to console output) add the `-framerate` input option:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 24 -i input.h264 -vf scale=1280:720 output.h264
```